# Saving a fetched result back into the database

Tags: php

i want know how I can save a result i fetched  from my database back into the database.

I selected and fetched a row from a table in my database, there is a column from the row i want to insert in another table in the same database. I tried to turn the $row['example']; to a variable but it wont work, i echo the variable to be sure if its working but its not showing .

please i need a help , below is my codes.

```
 <?php
         $query =mysqli_query ($dbconnect, "select * from stuprofile where     username ='$user' limit 1");

            while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>


             <?php
             $uname= "USERNAME :";
             $ebc= "EBC16";
             $id ="MATRIC NO : ";
             $wel = "WELCOME ";
             $name ="FIRSTNAME : ";
             $lname ="LASTNAME : ";
             $sex ="SEX : ";
             $add ="ADDRESS : ";
             $mob ="MOBILE : ";
             $inst ="INSTITUTION : ";
             $chap ="CHAPTER : ";
             $marr ="MARITAL STATUS : ";
             $lc ="LOCAL CHURCH : ";
             $bap ="BAPTISM : ";
             $baptised ="BAPTISED : ";
             $bank ="BANK : ";
             $teller ="TELLER NUMBER : ";
             $pay ="PAYMENT NUMBER : ";
             $email ="EMAIL : ";
             // dont forget to style your above varibles


            //<span id ="ty">
            ?> 


            <div class="wel">
            <?php
                     echo "<p>"  . $wel .  "<div id='ten' >" .  " " .     $row['firstname'] . "  " . $row['lastname'] . "</div>" . "<p>" . "<br />" ;

            ?>
            </div>
            <!--<section><img src= "images/egliselogocomp.jpg" height="310" width: 50px> </section>-->


            <p class= "names">

    <?php


                echo 
                    $id  .  "<span >" . $ebc . $row['id'].  "</span >" . "   <br />" .
                    $name  .  "<span >" . $row['firstname'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $lname .  "<span >" .$row['lastname'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $uname .  "<span >" .$row['username'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $sex    .  "<span >" .$row['sex'] . "</span >" . "<br />" . 
                    $add    .  "<span >" .$row['address'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $email .  "<span >" .$row['email'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $mob    .  "<span >" .$row['mobile'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $inst .  "<span >" .$row['institution'].  "</span >" . "<br />" . 
                    $chap   .  "<span >" .$row['chapter'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $marr .  "<span >" .$row['marital_status'].  "</span >" . "<br />" . 
                    $lc .    "<span >" .$row['local_church'].  "</span >" . "<br />".
                    $bap .  "<span >" .$row['baptised'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $baptised .  "<span >" .$row['baptism'].  "</span >" . "<br />" .
                    $bank .  "<span >" .$row['bank'].  "</span >" . "<br />" . 
                    $teller .    "<span >" .$row['teller_no'].  "</span >" . "<br />".
                    $pay .  "<span >" .$row['payment_date'].  "</span >" . "<br />";                

            }


            ?>
            </p>


    <?php



     } else {

         header("location: ebcreg.php");
     }
```

I need to insert the . $ebc . $row['id'] back into the database.

How do I do that please.
thanks

Comment: why you want to save this data again ? its updated or insert first time ?

Comment: You should learn about [`UPDATE` queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)...

Comment: I want to save it because i included a variable to the id i fetched. so i want to update the id and the variable back into the database.

Answer (score 0):

> mysqli_query($dbconnect, "INSERT INTO ....");

The same way you selected your data, just change your query.